# Use for loop with SQL statement to insert multiple values that increment by 1

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I use a for loop with a SQL insert statement to insert multiple rows where the values increment by 1 with each insert? In this example, I need the query to insert 66 rows while `county` and `value` increment by one until 66 is reached like: `county0`, `county1`, `county2`, etc. up to `county66`. The same would be true for `value`. Here's what I have:

```
for i in range (0, 65):
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO myTable (County, Value) VALUES (?, ?)', ('county'i, 'value'i))
    conn.autocommit = True
    executeImport = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting row by row, you could build a list of values and do a bulk insert using the `executemany()` function. That would be more efficient. So you could modify your code to do something like this:

```
values = [('county{}'.format(i), 'value{}'.format(i)) for i in range(0,67)]
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany("INSERT INTO myTable(County, Value) VALUES(?,?)", values)
conn.commit()
```

If you have Python 3.6 and above you could f-strings to build your list of values:

```
values = [(f'county{i}', f'value{i}') for i in range(0,67)]
```

Answer (score 0):

and what error you get or the result you get when run this???

Seem like occur some errors?

If error which statement execute... try

> ('county'i, 'value'i)

with ('county'+i, 'value'+i)